# Laravel pivot table relational data not retrieve

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have four table.

```
country
----------
id,name

service
----------
id,name

country_service
----------
id,country_id,service_id

country_service_rate
----------
id,country_service_id,rate
```

Now I want to get value of country_service_rate table row.

country_service model

```
public function rate(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\CountryServiceRate');
}
```

Service Model

```
public function country(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Country::class)->withPivot('id','is_base');
}
```

When I am trying to get data of pivot table related

```
$country->pivot->rate
```

getting null. But `$country->pivot` showing country_service table row data.

Here country have some rate value but it depends on service. A country have many service.Different service country have different rate value.

Comment: why you create country_service_rate table?

Comment: country have some rate value but it depends on service. a country have many service.different service country have different value.@JinalSomaiya

Comment: okay then add rate column to country_service table.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `CountryService` model I would not use a `belongsToMany` relationship.
I would define my relationships like:

`CountryService -> country() - belongsTo - Country::class()`

`CountryService -> service() belongsTo - Service::class()`

`CountryService -> rate() belongsTo - Rate::class()`

Or the other way since you want to access from country to rate:

`Country -> countryServices() - hasMany - CountryService::class`

`Service -> countryServices() - hasMany - CountryService::class`

For a `Country` then you can access its `countryServices`, but you still need a scope filtering for `service_id` to select which one of those `country_service` entries do you want, once you get the specific instance of `CountryService`, you can access its rate.